# Regular expression to match all search terms

Tags: regex

I need a regular expression that will match on all terms in a set of search terms. If the user types "bat sun" then I need to match any text entries that have words starting with "bat" AND starting with "sun".  So, "Sunday Batman" and "Batmobile sundance" should both match, but "Sunday" or "Batman" won't match because not all search terms are matched.

I'm using the expression within MongoDB (official C# driver) to support searching.

Thanks!

Comment: Split your search by spaces and iterate over your DB, checking if the field (lowercase) starts with one of the two (or more).

Comment: Do you have a regexp or anything you've tried already?

Comment: @James - I've tried "/(\\bsun|\\bbat)+/i" which works as a logical OR, but replacing | with && does not seem to give me a logical AND

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably a regex like below if you really want to use regex:

```
(?=.*\bsun)(?=.*\bbat).*
```

Of course you want to make it ignore case.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your definition of "word", you might be able to get away with using `\b` to match the beginning of a word.

As for checking for two results, it's much easier to do using two matches.

```
/\bsun/i && /\bbat/i          # Engines without implicit anchoring
/.*\bsun.*/i && /.*\bbat.*/i  # Engines with implicit anchoring
```

It can be done if your regex engine supports zero-width lookaheads.

```
/^(?=.*\bsun)(?=.*\bbat)/si   # Engines without implicit anchoring
/^(?=.*\bsun).*\bbat/si       # Engines without implicit anchoring
/(?=.*\bsun)(?=.*\bbat).*/si  # Engines with implicit anchoring
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do something along the lines of:

`.find( { Item: { $regex : /\b[Term1]/i, $regex : /\b[Term2]/i, $regex : /\b[TermN]/i } } );`

See: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-RegularExpressions