# MongoDB Query.And does not support matches

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I am running a search phrase against a MongoDB collection.  My phrase may have more than one term in it e.g. search for 'pete smit'.  I therefore need to use regular expressions to provide a 'starts with' function.  I am therefore creating an array of Query.Matches queries, adding them to a QueryComplete array, and then using a Query.And to run them.

Code is as follows:

```
// searchTerm will be something like 'pete smit'
string[] terms = searchTerm.Split(' ');

MongoDB.Driver.Builders.QueryComplete[] qca;
qca = new MongoDB.Driver.Builders.QueryComplete[terms.Length];
for (int i = 0; i < terms.Length; i++)
{
    regex = "/(\\b" + terms[i] + ")+/i"; // Good, but only single term (\b is start of word)
    qca[i] = MongoDB.Driver.Builders.Query.Matches("companyname", regex);
}
//MongoDB.Driver.Builders.QueryComplete qry = MongoDB.Driver.Builders.Query.Or(qca); // This works
MongoDB.Driver.Builders.QueryComplete qry = MongoDB.Driver.Builders.Query.And(qca); // This fails
```

On executing the Query.And I get an error stating:

```
Query.And does not support combining equality comparisons with other operators (field: 'companyname')
```

It works fine if I use Query.Or, but doesn't work if I use Query.And.  Can anyone suggest a workaround?  Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Until MongoDB supports $and all the subqueries passed to Query.And must be for different fields (so you can't apply different regular expressions to the same field).

Answer (score 0):

The workaround is to encapsulate the multiple search terms in a single regular expression, as follows:

```
string[] terms = searchTerm.Split(' ');
regex = "/";
for (int i = 0; i < terms.Length; i++)
{
    regex += "(?=.*\\b" + terms[i] + ")";
}
regex += ".*/i";
MongoDB.Driver.Builders.QueryComplete query = MongoDB.Driver.Builders.Query.Matches("companyname", regex); // The ^ matches the start of the string
```

See [Regular expression to match all search terms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6035301/regular-expression-to-match-all-search-terms)

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB's `$and` operator is now implemented and fully functional. See http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-%24and for usage so your original `MongoDB.Driver.Builders.Query.And(qca);` should now work.

[this is likely too late to help the original poster, but other users who find this question from a search can benefit]